# what is the primary domain in godaddy for?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, godaddy

I just bought the deluxe web-hosting service of godaddy and am very confused with the term "primary domain". What is this thing for and can I remove it so I can organize my websites in different directories.
/root/site1
/root/site2
/root/site3
....

PS I used to work with MediaTemple and remember that there was no primary domain....

please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Godaddy for some reason requires you to have a primary domain setup for each hosting account.  So this basically makes the root whatever the primary domain is.

There is a way that you can setup a false domain so that you can take the previous primary domain and move it. see the link here http://help.godaddy.com/article/4067

This will make the root non-web-accessible.  You basically create a false domain of anything you want as long as it isn't used by anyone else.  You can then move all your domains to a central area.

For instance my previous setup was this

```
/root/primary
/root/sites/site2
/root/sites/site3
```

After the switch I have

```
/root/falsedomain <--not web accessible as well as any folders at same level
/root/sites/site1 <--previous primary
/root/sites/site2
/root/sites/site3
```

Note that it can take some time to make the domain changes so if you have live sites they could be down for up to 24 hours.  I'm pretty sure you also won't be able to use some things Godaddy has like the "stats".

Comment: i have one more question for you. what is the folder "stats" for and what is the "cgi" for , too? Can I just delete them?

Comment: @Radi cgi -> http://help.godaddy.com/article/27?locale=en The stats folder can be accessed through your domain at http://youdomain.com/stats  You use the same credentials you would when logging into your account.  You can then see all kinds of things such as performance and errors on your sites.